# Using javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity to extract a list of strings from a JSON object

Tags: json, jax-rs

If my response is like:

```
{
  "values": [ "1", "2" ]
}
```

How should I use `readEntity` to populate a `List<String>` with the values: `1`, `2`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can read the entity as a `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map = 
    response.readEntity(new GenericType<Map<String, List<String>>>() { });
List<String> values = map.get("values");
```

Or define your own POJO:

```java
public class MyBean {

    private List<String> values;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
List<String> values = response.readEntity(MyBean.class).getValues();
```

You obviously must have a JSON provider such as Jackson registered.

Comment: This gives me the error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds response.readEntity(new GenericType<Map<String, List<String>>>() { });

Comment: @Baz My bad. It should be `Map<String, List<String>>` and not `Map<String, Object>`. I've fixed the error in my answer.